# Unauthorized Network

Tags: wi-fi

I recently configured my Samsung Galaxy Ace to provide internet access for my laptop. When friends visit and find the network, they get onto it and stream movies even though it is password protected. How can I identify the devices on the network  and disable other unauthorized devices from connecting to my network?

Comment: Change and don't tell them the password.. or tell them to leave, since they seem like bad friends as they're not listening to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Wifi tethering you can MAC filter it by only allowing certain devices to connect. Also make sure you have the password set and maybe even change it if you need to.